# Netbeans Style Breadcrumb in Editor for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any breadcrumb style navigation that you can have in IntelliJ like in the image below. This would be REALLY great if so. It helps tremendously in keeping track of what context I am in as well as navigation in the classes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is similiar breadcrumb navigation in the upper part of the window

[image].

Comment: But that only goes to the class/file level and not any further. I.e. the Netbeans breadcrumb will drill all the way down into to the if/try/for/etc. So say my cursor was in Foo.java in method getFoo(), inside an if (isFoo) then the breadcrumb would display: org.package.Foo > getFoo > if (isFoo)